# How to turn this write_all in non blocking function to write bytes through UDP?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, send

I have this function in C and I would like to use it to write bytes through my udp socket in non-blocking mode. I should complete the "TO BE DONE" part. Anyone could help me to understand what to do please? Does recalling the write function there could make any sense?

```
ssize_t nonblocking_write_all(int fd, const void *ptr, size_t n)
    {
        size_t n_left = n;
        while (n_left > 0) {
            ssize_t n_written = write(fd, ptr, n_left);
            if (n_written < 0) {
    
    /*** TO BE DONE START ***/
    
    
    /*** TO BE DONE END ***/
    
                if (n_left == n)
                    return -1; /* nothing has been written */
                else
                    break; /* we have written something */
            } else if (n_written == 0) {
                            continue;
            }
            n_left -= n_written;
            ptr += n_written;
        }
        assert(n - n_left >= 0);
        return n - n_left;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I just tried to post the problem as clear as possible, wasn't my intention just to outsource. Thank you for your suggestion, I will think how to edit the question then. I searched about this of course and read the man about system calls write and read, send and recv and I'm thinking about recalling write there but seems like just recalling the problem since I don't know where to shift the ptr then and if it makes sense..

Comment: Are you sure that the code you have is really intended for UDP? Because it assumes that a partial write might be done - which is not true with UDP. In general if errno is EAGAIN (or EWOULDBLOCK; which is the same on most systems) then the write can be retried, otherwise the write should be considered permanently failed.

Comment: Yes, in the case of full socket buffer. Ahhh, thanks, so if I understood well retrying write could make sense. Maybe using also poll() so I retry when actually the socket is ready. Meanwhile I'm trying to understand how actually generate this error so I can test, I guess I should block the read calls for a while from my server so it doesn't throw away the data from the socket buffer and it can be actually be filled or can be there any smarter way?

Comment: Like I said, I don't think that the code was originally intended to be used with UDP but it was intended for TCP. TCP is about a reliable byte stream while UDP is unreliable message (datagram) delivery. Each write will result in a single datagram send, so nothing partial and nothing to retry here actually. Even if the write succeeds the message might not be delivered and it will not be automatically retried.  Because the code makes no sense with UDP it will be impossible to make useful tests for it.

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right. I didn't specify that I'm checking and comparing the number of received bytes and the number of sent bytes. The purpose (not to be useful but for study reasons mainly) was to retry the write if the buffer is full so at the end I can measure how many bytes weren't send out of different totals and different servers. Anyway thank you very very much, your reflections helped me to get to the point :)

Comment: "nonblocking" and "write_all" are incompatible goals, unless you are guaranteed to always have enough outgoing-buffer-space to hold all the data you want to write.  Otherwise, when the outgoing-buffer gets full, you have to choose to either wait for the buffer to drain enough to fit the rest of the data you want to write (hence block), or return without writing all the data (hence not "all").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: n_written=nonblocking_write_all(fd,ptr,n_left);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).